Is it unfair for a journal to change a decision on an accepted paper if it is later found to be too derivative of the author's previous work?
I edit a journal and we have recently started using similarity checks.  We have a paper that we accepted, but before we published it we found that it is very similar to  previous papers of the author.
I don't know that it is plagiarism, but it only makes incremental progress, and pulls several introductory passages with only minute changes from other papers.  If we had seen this earlier would have editorially rejected it.
The reviewers did not notice the similarity, and it seems not uncommon in the particular area that this paper comes from.
Am I out of line to change the journal's decision on the paper? The paper was submitted a year ago, and has been 'accepted' for 6 months. The average submission to publication time in our field is about 1-2 years.
I don't think I feel right just changing the decision without a 'retraction' level accusation of plagiarism.  Would it be appropriate to at least ask that the introduction be rewritten to remove some of the similarity to previous works?

(1) Are the previous papers from which material is taken actually cited? (2) Would the "only incremental progress" be good enough that you'd still be OK to have this published in your journal, apart from pulling too much stuff from earlier papers? ("Incremental progress" is still progress...)

The results are properly cited. What is not made clear in the paper, but that the similarity check reveals, is that the proofs of the generalizations are mostly the same as the results that they are generalizing.   So I don't call it plagiarism.   Even if the writing were adjusted fixed, I think the progress is insignificant enough that I would not accept the paper.

Based on this I support the answer of @cbeleites.

Summary
IMHO, after the decision to accept (regardless whether it is before actual publication), taking back that acceptance is already a retraction and should thus be subject to the rules for retraction.

Long version

I don't know that it is plagiarism, but it only makes incremental progress, and pulls several introductory passages with only minute changes from other papers. If we had seen this earlier would have editorially rejected it.

As @Allure points out, plagiarism is a reason for retraction, and would be more than enough to correct the wrong decision of acceptance.
The "pulled from other papers" is difficult to judge for me: sometimes, once a good way of introducing a topic found, it can IMHO actually be good not to deviate from it for the sole sake of having new words*. But of course there's a limit to this, and above that it actually is plagiarism and likely also a copyright violation. Then @Allure's answer would apply.
I will assume  here that this boundary is not clearly crossed (according to your description).
While it is fine to never accept a paper that does not have sufficient novelty (i.e. is incremental), after acceptance it is IMHO too late for this.
In German we have a technical term Rechtsfrieden which may be translated as legal certainty. The idea behind that is that even if (here: adminstrative) errors happen, the certainty that decisions are done with and final is important as well. After the decision to accept, taking back that acceptance is IMHO a retraction and should thus happen only in cases that are sufficiently serious for retraction. I'd also call it a retraction then. Otherwise, the "acceptance" would only be a "preliminary acceptance before publication".
We do know that the review and editorial process is far from perfect, so maybe this is only of those papers that slipped in and that maybe shouldn't have but are also not a super-serious mistake.
So I'd say: You've made your bed, now you must lie on it. A mistake happened during the editorial process - that's unfortunate, but IMHO the thing to do now to learn from it and make sure it doesn't happen again - and otherwise move on.

* This convinced me: when writing one of my first papers, my prof told me: this is not a literature class where it's considered nice style to not repeat words. This is science, and the purpose is to communicate unambiguously, and to an audience that are mostly not native English speakers [including ourselves]. Use well-defined terms and easy and clear phrases and stick to them. We want the reader to put their mental work into understanding the topic, not the grammar or vocabulary.

Your answer confirms exactly what I was thinking with extreme clarity. Thank you.  We had decided that is was not academic plagiarism, and would not be retracted, so we could not change our decision.  We did, however ask the authors to re-write the introduction so that there is less a danger of copyright infringement.
The point that once the right introduction is found there seems no need to deviate just to have new words is an interesting take.  Certainly on the scale of a sentence I can agree, but when it gets to half a page, it might be pushing it.

Plagiarism undetected at acceptance is one of the best reasons for rejecting a paper post-acceptance, since it's uncontroversial (it's good enough cause for retraction, and the paper isn't actually published yet). So yes, you are allowed to do this, especially since as an editor of the journal you have carte blanche over what gets published (up to the editor-in-chief overruling you). You are also allowed to request the introduction to be rewritten, if you feel that's more appropriate than retracting the 'accept' decision.
More concerning is how this paper got to acceptance in the first place. Why didn't the publisher do a plagiarism check? How did you not notice it only makes incremental progress? How is the paper still not published six months after acceptance?
If you do decide to reject the paper, it's ideal to tell the publisher to hold off on publishing the paper ASAP. The fact that the paper is still not published after six months suggests the bulk of the typesetting work is already done and something else is causing the holdup (e.g. author is unable to pay the APC), but even in this case, the issues could be fixed any moment, so tell them as soon as possible.

We are a small journal and only recently have been able to do similarity checks.  We weren't able to do them when it was submitted.
The 'six months' is due to a publishing backlog.  If not in all fields, this is quite common for mathematics journals.
I'm not sure why the reviewers didn't notice the incremental progress. The reviews were positive, but not very thorough. I guess I should have tried to get a couple more of them.
